# Tapestry 5 user authentication

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry

I was following the very slim tutorial on the Tapestry website for Tapestry 5 and was introduced to very basic database interactions but not how to do user authentication.  Where do I go for more comprehensive guidance in tapestry 5?  I went to the tapestry wiki (http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowTos) but I wasn't really looking for a bunch of how-to's.  Do you know of any good sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can 'roll your own' or use one of the 3rd party modules such as tynamo's [tapestry-security](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-security+guide). even if you do write your own, it's a good idea to see how others have implemented it so have a look at the [source](http://svn.tynamo.codehaus.org/browse/tynamo/trunk/tapestry-security).

my first attempt at writing my own security module had me creating a class hierarchy for all my components and pages (inheritance supplied security checks) which does not really follow the tapestry paradigm.

unfortunately it seems fashionable for tapestry and all tapestry modules to have sparse documentation.

Comment: for me, the most important thing about learning a framework is documentation and support...tapestry is giving me problems with this

Comment: get on the mailing list, there's no other way! yes the documentation sucks, but once you get past that first bit of the learning curve it's really quite nice.

Comment: The Tapestry documentation has improved quite a bit in the last 2 months and ongoing.

Answer (score 4):

If you need something robust you are probably going to want to use something like Shiro or Spring's security.  Both of those can be integrated with Tapestry.  Tapestry-security basically just gives you access to Shiro and you can use the Shiro documentation to figure out anything you need to know. Shiro works very well and you can protect pages as well as methods.  It has a number of different options so it can be confusing at first as you try to figure out which parts you need, but it doesn't take too much to get started with.

A couple other ideas to look at:

You might try taking a look at the demo application here:
http://tapestry.zones.apache.org:8180/tapestry5-hotel-booking/signin

And the source for it here:
https://github.com/ccordenier/tapestry5-hotel-booking/

Also take a look at application here:
http://wookicentral.com/

And the source for it here: https://github.com/spreadthesource/wooki